# Syntax Highlighter in Asp.net or Silverlight

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, syntax-highlighting

I want syntax highlighter for in Asp.net that highlight code of languages like C# ,JAVA ,Html
 and Rearrange code in Systematic way

any other highlighter then http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

It Should Display HTML tag

else any Syntax highlighter available in Silverlight 4.0

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter? IMHO, it's the best available syntax highlighter.

Comment: it doesnt work well with html tag

Answer (score 1):

see a link:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-syntax-highlighters-to-beautify-code-presentation/

Answer (score 0):

You can try out http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/aspnet/codehighlighter/